# Fallout 4 Launcher Loop

Tags: fallout-4

I've recently come back to playing Fallout 4 after a while. After playing around 10 hours or so (4th day of playing), my Fallout 4 Launcher is stuck in a **loop**.

I've searched online for solutions (Run as admin/change name) but nothing has worked. I usually launch the game through Nvidia GeForce, and it's always worked. 
Apparently it's a steam problem, but I still haven't figured out how to start the game.

If you require my specs, please specify (although I'm sure it doesn't affect the outcome)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "loop"? Do you have any mods installed? Have you tried checking the local files of the game through the steam client? Any new hardware installed recently?

Comment: Definitely need more info on the actual problem. What do you mean it is "stuck in a loop"? What happens? When?

Comment: I think the OP had the same problem I had recently with Skyrim: clicking 'Play' in the launcher closes the launcher and reopens it, without starting the game's executable. In my case, it had something to do with the SKSE, I *think*.

Comment: @Wulfinite Did you have F4SE installed?